# Remove Event Listener In an Object Literal Lost this reference

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Currently working on a small project using an OLOO style approach.
[Problem found here](https://jsbin.com/kufepeyitu/edit?js,console,output)

So the issue I am facing is that I have an event handler.

```
eventHandler: function() {
    console.log('Hit');
    testSelector.removeEventListener('click', this.eventHandler, false);
  }
```

Now what happens is that I want this to be removed after the first click. However this does not seem to work as I expected. I am binding the object this reference yet there seems to be something that I am missing in what is actually going on here. Would anyone be able to clarify what is actually happening or where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in OLOO, but I can see two issues in your example:

- the `this` inside an eventListener callback handler refers to the node so you need to take care you're referencing the same `this` in both methods ( `add/removeEventListener` )
- `removeEventListener` won't work if the listener parameter isn't the same as `addEventListener`, and when you use `bind` you're actually creating a new function (so you have to keep track of that to)

in code:

```
var testSelector = document.querySelector('.test');

var object = {
  init: function() {
    this.ref = this.eventHandler.bind(this)
    testSelector.addEventListener('click', this.ref, false);
  },
  eventHandler: function() {
    console.log('Hit');
    testSelector.removeEventListener('click', this.ref, false);
  }
}

object.init();
```

https://jsbin.com/hejenuraba/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly the answer I was looking for. 

Edited your answer slightly to bind the this.ref to an actual property. And also removed the self = this as the bind will handle that for you.

https://jsbin.com/kufepeyitu/2/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Do you see any reason why you have to assign it to another property if you had to go testSelector.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandler.bind(this), false); ? As debugging this it doesnt log that it is referencing the node but the outer object which is what confused me.

Comment: using bind you  have it point to  `object` but unless you get a reference to  the binded  function you lose it, and then you can't reference it in the `removeEventListener`; hope it makes sense..

Comment: So basically when the bind() happened it loses its reference to the correct this as it was in a addEventListener as well? 

Makes sense was just strange when looking at the debugger when going into the actual eventHandler method the 'this' reffered to the object. So that. But from what I can tell by doing the bind outside of the eventListener we are then able to apply the correct reference to this that we actually wanted on the bind returned function.

Comment: I'm editing the question: actually the referece to this is already binded , just need to keep track of the resulting function

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in my environment as follows:

```
var testSelector;
var eventHandler = function(){
    console.log('Hit');
    testSelector.removeEventListener('click', eventHandler, false);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    testSelector = this.getElementById('btn');
    testSelector.addEventListener('click',eventHandler);
});
```

You code looks fine but you may want to cross check the following:

In your line of code:

```
testSelector.removeEventListener('click', this.eventHandler, false);
```

Make sure you have the references to testSelector and eventHandler

Comment: Debugging this it has the correct reference to 'this', which is the confusing part, as we are binding the this reference correctly. The above solution we are just avoiding javascripts 'this' completely which I cant do unfortunatly as im trying to find a solution to why my remove isnt working.